# installed bower how to use it

Tags: bower, bower-install, main-bower-files

I have installed bower through Solutions Package Manager in VS 2017. I obviously want to use it.

I'm confused because that only created cmd files (node, bower & git) in a new .bin folder. No components folder or json or anything else.

Shall I run bower init somewhere (where? a command line). When I'm trying to do it it asks me for a 'name' . Name of what I should give? Will that be a bower json file or components folder name or something else? What other questions will it ask?

All bower manuals I find say to do the install and then do bower install of a package (from a command line I guess?)

And where do I perform 'bower search'?

https://bower.io/

On the other hand when I tried to run this command (before I installed Bower package from solutions manager) in nuget console:

```
npm install -g bower
```

I got an error:

```
npm : npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0: ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend Yarn and Webpack for *new* front-end projects! Yarn's advantage is security and reliability, and Webpack's is support for both CommonJS and AMD 
projects. Currently there's no migration path but we hope you'll help us figure out one.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g bower
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN deprec...figure out one.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: its seems like a issue with At line:1 char:1.not bower issue